# Facebook apps and herouku cloud

Tags: facebook, heroku, cloud, vps

Is smart to use a free cloud for facebook app - heroku (5mb limit) or use own VPS?

I plan to build an FB app and trying to chose hosting?

What you suggest?

Is Heroku cloud platform a complicated for developmet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't criticize Heroku cloud or any other free services, but I am strong believer of using Paid services only. Free service is never a free, there is always a string attached ...

I would suggest you to use Paid VPS or Cloud solutions.

Comment: :) 5 MB is too small ... If you install SQL 2008 Express or Web Edition, you can easily get up to 10 GB of free database on Windows VPS ...